# No content encoding in response header

Tags: tomcat, gzip, content-encoding, response-headers

server.xml file in /Tomcat 6.0/conf is given below.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <!--Initialize Jasper prior to webapps are loaded. Documentation at /docs/jasper-howto.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
  <!-- JMX Support for the Tomcat server. Documentation at /docs/non-existent.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.ServerLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />

  <GlobalNamingResources>    
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <Service name="Catalina">  

<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443"
 useSendfile="false" compression="force" noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
 compressionMinSize="10" compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/json,text/javascript,text/css,text/plain,application/javascript,application/xml,application/xml+xhtml"/>

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />

    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
             resourceName="UserDatabase"/>

    <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
            xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

I referred a lot of sites. All are saying same thing. I also did like that. But why I cant make the desired output. gzip is not working. **No content encoding in response header**. Anything I missed?

Answer (score 0):

There some extra setting required for tomcat to understand gziped response

[Try this link](http://learningviacode.blogspot.in/2012/11/gzip-your-tomcat-response.html)